# Why do I have to say "want you to do" instead of "want you do"

Tags: grammar

example: "I want you to eat fish" instead of "I want you eat fish" or "I want that you eat fish".

Can you explain to me what is te grammatical reason for this?

Comment: The first is correct. The second is a term of endearment to someone named "eat fish". Finally, the third is rudely calling someone "eat fish" because they have something you want.

Comment: You probably are looking for clarification on using infinitives (bare vs full)

Comment: Because some verbs require _to_ with following infinitives, and _want_ is one of them. There are some that don't, but they are very common and idiomatic verbs like _have, make,_ or _let._

Answer (score 2):

> You probably are looking for clarification on using infinitives (bare vs full)

Hefewe1zen

> Because some verbs require *to* with following infinitives, and *want* is one of them. There are some that don't, but they are very common and idiomatic verbs like *have*, *make*, or *let*.

John Lawler

Comment: You can find more details by looking up _English Catenative Verbs_ at Wiktionary.